# How to properly restart server socket?

Tags: c, sockets

Once in a while my server `accept` functions just stop working properly anymore.

There is a much deeper story behind this, I'm being flooded with `SYN` and `SYN/ACK` packets, my network router goes disco and `accept` keeps returning `ECONNABORTED`.... I already tried to debug and fix this specific attack, but without success. By now I gave up and rather look for a more generic server recover solution.

Anyway I figured out that simpy "restarting" the server socket by closing and calling `socket` again is helping. Theoretically very simple, but practically I'm facing here a huge challenge because (a) the server is quite complex by now and (b) when should I exactly restart the server socket.

My setup is one accept-thread that calls `accept` and feeds `epoll`, one listener-thread that listens for `epoll` read/write etc. events and feeds a queue of a thread pool.

I have not found any literature that guides one through restarting the server socket.

Particularly:

- When do I actually restart the server socket? I mean I do not really know if a `ECONNABORTED` return value from `accept` is just a aborted connection or the `accept`/filedescriptor is going banana.
- How does closing the server socket affect epoll and connected clients? Should I close the server socket immediately or rather have a buffer time such that all clients have finished first?
- Or is it even best to have two alternating server sockets such that if one goes banana I just try the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making some assumptions about the things you say in your question all being true and accurate even though some of them seems like they may be misdiagnosed. Unfortunately, you didn't really explain how you reached the conclusions presented, so I really can't do much other than assume they're true.

For example, you don't explain how or why you figured that closing and calling `socket` again will help. From just the information you gave, I would strongly suspect the opposite is true. But again, without knowing the evidence and rationale that lead you to figure that, all I can do is assume it's true despite my instinct and experience saying it's wrong.

> When do I actually restart the server socket? I mean I do not really know if a ECONNABORTED return value from accept is just a aborted connection or the accept/filedescriptor is going banana.

If it really is the case that accepting connections will recover faster from a restart than without one and you really can't get any connections through, keep track of the last successful connection and the number of failures since the last successful connection. If, for example, you've gone 120 seconds or more without a successful connection and had at least four failed connections since the last successful one, then close and re-open. You may need to tune those parameters.

> How does closing the server socket affect epoll and connected clients?

It has no effect on them unless you're using `epoll` on the server socket itself. In that case, make sure to remove it from the set before closing it.

> Should I close the server socket immediately or rather have a buffer time such that all clients have finished first?

I would suggest "draining" the socket by calling `accept` without blocking until it returns `EWOULDBLOCK`. Then you can `close` it. If you get any legitimate connections in that process, don't `close` it since it's obviously still working.

A client that tries to get in between your `close` and getting around to calling `listen` on a new socket might get an error. But if they're getting errors anyway, that should be acceptable.

> Or is it even best to have two alternating server sockets such that if one goes banana I just try the other one.

A long time ago, port DoS attacks were common because built-in defenses to things like SYN-bombs weren't as good as they are now. In those days, it was common for a server to support several different ports and for clients to try the ports in rotation. This is why IRC servers often accepted connections on ranges of ports such as 6660-6669. That meant an attacker had to do ten times as much work to make all the ports unusable. These days, it's pretty rare for an attack to take out a specific inbound port so the practice has largely gone away. But if you are facing an attack that can take out specific listening ports, it might make sense to open more listening ports.

Or you could work harder to understand the attack and figure out why you are having a problem that virtually nobody else is having.